# Meaning/structure of "so als"

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

> Gleich mehrere Kernaussagen hatte das Kanzleramt zuvor in der Bevölkerung testen lassen, so als handelte es sich um eine neue Margarine-Reklame - und nicht um die Begründung eines zentralen Regierungsvorhabens.

What is the meaning of "so als handelte es sich ..." here? Is it like

> sodass es war, als ob es sich um ... handelte

?

Also, is the use of "handelte" here the Konjunktiv II?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In short:** *als* alongside a conjunctive II corresponds to *as if*:

> Er läuft, als ginge es um sein Leben.

```
He runs, as if his life depended on it.
```

*So* is an adverb with no own meaning, it just points to the actual description - the comparison starting with *als*. 
A construction with *sodass* is not possible, because it's not a comparison, and yes, *handelte* is conjuntive II.

---

First, it's important to see that removing *so* doesn't change the meaning:

> Gleich mehrere Kernaussagen hatte das Kanzleramt zuvor in der Bevölkerung testen lassen, als handelte es sich um eine neue Margarine-Reklame [...].

```
The White House did blabla, as if blublu.
```

Here, *als* is a conjunction. It describes two approaches using a comparison (critisizing en passant). The "function" of *so* is maybe easier explained with an additional comma:

> Gleich mehrere Kernaussagen hatte das Kanzleramt zuvor in der Bevölkerung testen lassen, so**,** als handelte es sich um eine neue Margarine-Reklame [...].

```
The White House did blabla, in a way, as if blublu.
```

So, *so* is an appended Adverb(ial), describing the first sentence. "Appended", because the sentence could just as well look like

> Gleich mehrere Kernaussagen hatte das Kanzleramt zuvor in der Bevölkerung **so** testen lassen, als handelte es sich um eine neue Margarine-Reklame [...].

But as *so* doesn't have any actual meaning itself (except when demonstrating physical properties face-to-face), it has to be described in turn, and that is achieved with the comparison. One could say that it stands representative for what is conveyed by the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I'd translate "als ob" as "as if". "Handelte" is Konjunktiv Präteritum (II). Actually, it is possible to use Konjunktiv Präsens (I, handele) here as well.

I don't quite get your question about "sodass es war, als ob es sich um ... handelte". Do you want to use it as a replacement in this sentence?